# Error in giving variable name as table name

Tags: mysql, node.js

There is an error in giving the variable name as the table name in MySQL and nodejs.
giving such error Error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''THETABLE' `(id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT, PRIMARY
>   KEY(id))' at line 1`

```
var tableName = 'THETABLE';

var tableDef = "CREATE TABLE ? (id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))";

db.query(tableDef, [tableName], function (err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Table created");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use prepared statements for the table names, you should do it with string concat:

```
var tableName = 'THETABLE';

var tableDef = "CREATE TABLE ";
tableDef=tableDef.concat(tableName," (id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))");

db.query(tableDef, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Table created");
});
```